# Interpretation of partition function and thermodynamic potential

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics

So in the microcanonical ensemble the partition function $\Omega$ counts the number of microstates for a given $(NVE)$ configuaration and $S =  k_B \ln (\Omega)$ is the entropy. The most likely state is the one that maximizes $S$.

Now I was wondering if there is a similar interpretation of a partition function $Z$ and the quantity $ \ln(Z)$ for the other ensembles. So, does a partition function always count microstates? But apparently $\ln(Z)$ is also always an important quantity (Helmholtz energy and so on). My question is: Why? Is this always the quantity that is maximized in the most likely configuration or why do we care about $ln(Z)$?

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Comment: I am actually confused as to what you are trying to ask here. $Z$ precisely represents the sum total of all configurations available to the system. The proof for $ln(Z)$ maximizing the entropy can be done using maximum information transferred. The relation between Helmholtz energy and $ln Z$ is valid only in NVE ensemble. The definition of partition function is different for different ensemble as well.

Comment: The $lnZ$ is needed to normalize the probability space for the partition function to show that certain macrostates are more probable because they have a large number of microstates in their ensemble